# dbt.exceptions.UndefinedMacroException: Compilation Error '{macro_name}' is undefined

Tags: dbt

Using dbt-core@1.2.6, dbt-bigquery@1.2.1,

Given the following macro:

`macros/generate_dataset_name.sql`

```
{% macro generate_dataset_name(type) -%}
    {%- if type is none -%}
        {{env_var('ENV_PREFIX')}}_{{env_var('CLIENT_ID')}}
    {%- elif type == "industry" -%}
        {{env_var('ENV_PREFIX')}}_industry
    ...
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endmacro %}
```

With the following document file:

`macros/generate_dataset_name.yml`

```yaml
version: 2

macros:
  - name: generate_dataset_name
    arguments:
      - name: type
        type: string
```

and the following `dbt_project.yml` file, that uses said macro directly in it:

```
name: 'analytics'
version: '1.0.0'
config-version: 2

profile: 'dbt'

model-paths: ["models"]
# ...
macro-paths: ["macros"]
snapshot-paths: ["snapshots"]

target-path: "target"
clean-targets:
  - "target"

models:
  # resource-paths
  analytics:
    +schema: "{{generate_dataset_name()}}"
    mart:
      industry:
        +schema: "{{generate_dataset_name('industry')}}"
```

Running `dbt compile` results in the following error:

```
18:00:13  Encountered an error:
Compilation Error
  Could not render {{generate_dataset_name()}}: 'generate_dataset_name' is undefined
18:00:13  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbt/clients/jinja.py", line 494, in catch_jinja
    yield
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbt/clients/jinja.py", line 526, in render_template
    return template.render(ctx)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbt/clients/jinja.py", line 178, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbt/clients/jinja.py", line 135, in quoted_native_concat
    head = list(islice(nodes, 2))
  File "<template>", line 1, in top-level template code
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/sandbox.py", line 460, in call
    if not __self.is_safe_callable(__obj):
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/sandbox.py", line 360, in is_safe_callable
    getattr(obj, "unsafe_callable", False) or getattr(obj, "alters_data", False)
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'generate_dataset_name' is undefined
```

I made sure to check that:

1. The macro uses proper tags (`{% macro ... %}` instead of `{ % macro ... % }` (space difference)
2. The macro is valid jinja2
3. The name of the macro is the same as its file, and free from typos
4. The file is within a folder that is loaded by dbt as a macros- folder
5. The macro is documented with a YAML file.
6. Changing all calls of `generate_dataset_name()` to `generate_dataset_name('some-supported-value')` doesn't solve the issue (in case it's like for SQL procedures, where `fn()` is a different function from `fn(TEXT)`)

Any idea of what could be the source of this error?
Am I supposed to be able to use macros directly in `dbt_project.yml` or is this unsupported?

Comment: Removing all the calls to the macro from ALL the yaml files (including the model declaration files) solves the issue. I'm still curious if macros are supported directly in yaml files!